# How to see every thread use how many resources(cpu,memory,io) in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I'm using resin,sometime the load very high,so I particularly want to see inner the JVM process all of the threads state,how many cpu or memory or disckIO every thread using.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you'll find something useful here: http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers

Answer (score 4):

If using the HotSpot provided by Oracle/Sun launch `jvisualvm` and attach it to Resin.
Java VisualVM allows you to see what the application is doing at thread level.

See this link:
[Java VisualVM Monitoring Application Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html)

Comment: +1 This is the best place to start. For more detail you can use a commercial profiler like YourKit.